# how to chart the last 90 elements of an array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been able to chart 90 days of A1C levels when I had only 90 days worth of data, but now I'm keeping a year worth of data, how do I chart the last 90 days? here is what I have...[image: A bar graph of my wife's data for only 90 days]  What I would like is a bar graph of the last 90 days for the year. here is a section of code that creates the graph  for only 90 days...

```
const dataTimes3 = readings.map((data) => {
  return readings.reduce(
    (Totaldata, readings) =>
      (Totaldata = parseFloat(
        (0.0461538461538 * (data.sugarB + data.sugarL + data.sugarD)) / 3,
        10
      )),
    0
  );
});
const colordataTimes3 = readings.map((data) => {
  return readings.reduce(
    (Totaldata, readings) => (
      (Totaldata = parseFloat(
        (0.0461538461538 * (data.sugarB + data.sugarL + data.sugarD)) / 3,
        10
      )),
      Totaldata <= Number(5.6)
        ? 'rgba(0,0,255,0.6)'
        : Totaldata >= Number(5.6) && Totaldata <= Number(6.5)
        ? 'rgba(255,255,0,0.6)'
        : Totaldata >= Number(6.5) && Totaldata <= Number(7.5)
        ? 'rgba(0,255,0,0.6)'
        : Totaldata >= Number(7.5) && Totaldata <= Number(8.5)
        ? 'rgba(255,165,0,0.6)'
        : Totaldata >= Number(8.5)
        ? 'rgba(255,0,0,0.6)'
        : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)'
    ),
    0
  );
});
const borderdataTimes3 = readings.map((data) => {
  return readings.reduce(
    (Totaldata, readings) => (
      (Totaldata = parseFloat(
        (0.0461538461538 * (data.sugarB + data.sugarL + data.sugarD)) / 3,
        10
      )),
      Totaldata <= Number(5.6)
        ? 'rgba(0,0,255,1)'
        : Totaldata >= Number(5.6) && Totaldata <= Number(6.5)
        ? 'rgba(255,255,0,1)'
        : Totaldata >= Number(6.5) && Totaldata <= Number(7.5)
        ? 'rgba(0,255,0,1)'
        : Totaldata >= Number(7.5) && Totaldata <= Number(8.5)
        ? 'rgba(255,165,0,1)'
        : Totaldata >= Number(8.5)
        ? 'rgba(255,0,0,1)'
        : 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'
    ),
    0
  );
});
```

can anyone help me to make this the last 90 days instead of the first 90 days?

Comment: You could just slice the array based on the max length and the number of days that you want. But the code is kinda hard to read, could you let me know which array contains the readings?

Comment: it is in dataTimes3 section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slice the original array which is `dataTimes3` and only take the last 90 elements, this will always take the last 90 elements regardless of the length of the array. Then use `lastNinetyDays` to plot the data.

```
const days = 90
const lastNinetyDays = dataTimes3.slice(Math.max(dataTimes3.length - days, 0))
```

**Edit**:

You can also index the array using negative indexing

```
const lastNinetyDays = dataTimes3.slice(-days)
```

**Example:**

```js
const a = [...Array(100).keys()]
console.log(a.slice(-90))
```

Comment: it looks like that did it for 3 times per day..  just curious would i just make a call to that same line of code for 1,2,4 and 5 times a day?

Comment: @WesleyOwen ah ok so yes you would have to call this for each of those days.

Comment: one more question, would I do the same thing for the colors and the borders?, cause the percentages are matching but the colors and borders are not...

Comment: If the colors and borders arrays contain the specific color and border for a particular day then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `readings` array is ordered chronologically, you can reverse the order of your array by calling the Array object's `reverse` method and assign the result to a new variable. Then you can perform the logic of each map call.

Link to the reverse method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Comment: it didn't work, was I supposed to put it into the dataTimes3 at the head of it?